# FMDB and index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fmdb

I am going crazy trying to debug this. I am trying to basically duplicate a row in my SQLite db and increment a value. I have used similar insert statements elsewhere in my code and had no problems, but this time it is not cooperating. The program errors when it gets to the executeUpdate statement.

I am relatively new to iOS programming and have gone as far as I can on my own.

Here is my function:

```
+ (BOOL)updatePetWithNewVet:(NSNumber *)i {

    NSString *appSupportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *dbPath = [appSupportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pets.sqlite"];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];

    [database open];

    FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"Select * from vets order by vetID desc limit 1"];
    if ([results next]) {

        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        NSInteger vID = [results intForColumn:@"vetID"];
        NSInteger vID2 = vID+1;
        NSNumber *newVetID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:vID2];
        NSString *vName = [results stringForColumn:@"vetName"];
        NSString *vPhone = [results stringForColumn:@"vetPhone"];
        NSString *vStreet = [results stringForColumn:@"vetStreet"];
        NSString *vCity = [results stringForColumn:@"vetCity"];
        NSString *vState = [results stringForColumn:@"vetState"];
        NSNumber *vZipcode = [f numberFromString:[results stringForColumn:@"vetZipcode"]];

        NSLog(@"%@", vName);
        NSLog(@"%@", vPhone);
        NSLog(@"%@", vStreet);
        NSLog(@"%@", vCity);
        NSLog(@"%@", vState);
        NSLog(@"%@", vZipcode);

        NSLog(@"VET ID: %ld", (long)vID);
        NSLog(@"NEW VET ID: %@", newVetID);

        [results close];

        [database executeUpdateWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO vets (vetID, vetName, vetPhone, vetStreet, vetCity, vetState, vetZipcode) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", newVetID, vName, vPhone, vStreet, vCity, vState, vZipcode, nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", [database lastErrorMessage]);
    }

    [database close];

    return 1;
}
```

And it is not working. This is what get when I crash:

```
2014-11-29 09:35:54.722 PetJournal[58823:8400345] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb37f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e7d0bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea22f33 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227
    3   PetJournal                          0x000000010cc1744e -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] + 2542
    4   PetJournal                          0x000000010cc17fa8 -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:withArgumentsInArray:] + 152
    5   PetJournal                          0x000000010cc1834d -[FMDatabase executeUpdateWithFormat:] + 637
    6   PetJournal                          0x000000010cc54fd7 +[UIView(Database) updatePetWithNewVet:] + 1159
    7   PetJournal                          0x000000010cc549d2 +[UIView(Database) createPetNamed:withBirthday:] + 1522
    8   PetJournal                          0x000000010cc3165e -[AddPetViewController savePet:] + 398
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d07a8be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d181410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d1807df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d0c0308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d0c0c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d08d9b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d09aa7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d076103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea6d551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea6341d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea62a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea62486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001114139f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010d079420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  PetJournal                          0x000000010cc33f63 main + 115
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f2d2145 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Comment: Didn't change anything, but I added it in for safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `executeUpdateWithFormat`, but are not using `printf`-style syntax in your SQL. Either use `executeUpdateWithFormat` with `printf`-style format string, or use `executeUpdate` with the `?` placeholders.

Personally, I'd suggest you just use `executeUpdate` (and drop the `nil` from the end of the list).

Comment: I've tried that before and am now trying it again, but what happens now is that the program freezes. No errors or crashes in the log, just the program coming to a standstill.

Comment: I did. It is freezing on the executeUpdate line.

Comment: Then that would suggest that you must have some other query open on this database that would be locking this table.

Comment: You were right. I had another query open that when fixed, this worked perfectly. If you update your answer to mention my db being locked because of that, I will mark it correct.

Comment: The original question says nothing about freezing, but rather is solely about "beyond bounds" with `executeUpdateWithFormat`, which I tried to answer above. It makes no sense for me to edit my answer to cover a topic not raised in the original question. Frankly, while I was happy to help, the discussion of locking queries is completely unrelated and doesn't belong in this question at all (and, besides, the locking issue is discussed exhaustively elsewhere on S.O. and doesn't need to be covered again here, whereas your `executeUpdateWithFormat` issue is somewhat novel).